# ts-mocha test does not work with node-fetch

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I've installed ts-mocha, node-fetch and want to run a unit test with it. However I'm getting:

> TypeError: Unknown file extension ".ts" for ...

The code in this file is:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

export default async () => {
  return fetch('https://github.com/');
}
```

My unit test is:

```
import { expect } from 'chai'; 
import useFetch from './useFetch';

describe("useFetch", function() {
  before(async () => {
    await import ('./useFetch');
  });

  describe("get", async () => {
    it("test", async () => {
      const result = await useFetch();

      expect(result).to.equal('fail');
    });
  });
});
```

The function is being called. Whenever I remove the fetch from the function the error disappears.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What command did you use to run the test?

Answer (score 0):

Take the `async` out of the `describe` function.

```
import { expect } from 'chai'; 
import useFetch from './useFetch';

describe("useFetch", function() {
  before(async () => {
    await import ('./useFetch');
  });

  // no async in describe
  describe("get", () => {
    it("test", async () => {
      const result = await useFetch();

      expect(result).to.equal('fail');
    });
  });
});
```

Couldn't test it but [here is a reference](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mocha/async).